# "user not registered" when trying to login and "There has been a critical error" message on site

Tags: login

I'm having trouble accessing my site. I've been building my site online for a couple of days now. I've added some new themes and plug-ins which I'm guessing is the root of my problems and why the critical error message is popping up. But I can't even log in to check my admin email box. And when I tried to reset my password it won't allow me as it says my username and email are not registered. I've cleared my cache, browsing history, and cookies, but still no luck.
If anyone could help me out that would be great!

Comment: "check my admin email box" - you're definitely trying to log into WordPress? WordPress doesn't do email.

Comment: If you're having trouble logging into the site then there are instructions for resetting the password several different ways here https://wordpress.org/support/article/resetting-your-password/ including directly in the database.